# Where is the ethLogObservable method in Web3j?

Tags: web3j

I can´t find where is the Web3j ethLogObservable method. I can´t find in [GitHub](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/search?q=ethLogObservable&type=Code) repo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From its version 4.0, web3j started using **RxJava 2.0 FLowable** instead of **RxJava 2.0 Obsersable** to handle events processing, notably because Flowable are much more efficient during high load using a *backpressure* mechanism.

The new function to catch events is now the following:

```
EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(
        DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, 
        DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, 
        contractAddress);

web3.ethLogFlowable(filter).subscribe(event -> {
    log.info("event = {}", event);
});
```

You can find more info [here](https://docs.web3j.io/filters_and_events/)

EDIT: fixed URL

Answer (score 0):

I can't run ethLogFlowable...

The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the subscribe() method call. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling

Comment: It doesn't seems to be an answer. What are you trying to say?

Comment: if you check `subscribe` method, there's an overload for it that plus the `onNext` block, accepts `onError` block too. You should pass a function to this argument so further errors will be handled.